# Android service not stopping after cancelling

Tags: android, android-widget, android-service, alarmmanager, repeatingalarm

I have widget that start 2 services using AlaramManager and running them repeatedly:

```
public static final String TAG = "RotterWidgetProvider";
public static ArrayList<SubjectObject> subjectsList;
public static boolean isUpdated=true;
public static int currentSubject=0;
private PendingIntent serviceShowNextSubject = null;  
private PendingIntent serviceDownloadSubjects = null;
Intent i=null;
Intent i2=null;

@Override
public void onUpdate(final Context context, final AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,int[] appWidgetIds) 
{
  RemoteViews remoteView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.rotter_appwidget_layout);
  Intent launchAppIntent = new Intent(context, WidgetSettings.class);
  PendingIntent launchAppPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
           0, launchAppIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
     remoteView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imgWidgetSettings, launchAppPendingIntent);
  if(subjectsList==null)
  {
     remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.txtSubject,"נא לחכות, טוען נתונים");
     ComponentName RotterListWidget = new ComponentName(context,
                RotterWidgetProvider.class);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(RotterListWidget, remoteView);

       final AlarmManager m = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);  

        final Calendar TIME = Calendar.getInstance();  
        TIME.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);  
        TIME.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);  
        TIME.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);  

        if(i==null)
        {
           i = new Intent(context, UpdateRotterWidgetService.class); 
           Log.v(TAG,"UpdateRotterWidgetService Created");
        }
        if(i2==null)
        {
           i2 = new Intent(context, DownloadSubjectsService.class); 
           Log.v(TAG,"DownloadSubjectsService Created");
        }

        if (serviceShowNextSubject == null)  
        {  
           serviceShowNextSubject = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT); 
           Log.v(TAG,"serviceShowNextSubject initialized");
        }  
        if(serviceDownloadSubjects==null)
        {
           serviceDownloadSubjects=PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, i2, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT); 
           Log.v(TAG,"serviceDownloadSubjects initialized");
        }

        SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context.getApplicationContext());
        String subjectsDownloadInterval=settings.getString("SubjectsDownloadInterval", "10");
        String subjectsUpdateInterval=settings.getString("SubjectsUpdateInterval", "10");
        int down=10;
        int upd=10;
        try
        {
           down=Integer.parseInt(subjectsDownloadInterval);
           upd=Integer.parseInt(subjectsUpdateInterval);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
        m.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, TIME.getTime().getTime(), 1000 * 60*down, serviceDownloadSubjects);
        m.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, TIME.getTime().getTime(), 1000 * upd, serviceShowNextSubject); 


  }
}
```

After i delete Widget from the screen i am cancelling the services:

```
@Override  
public void onDisabled(Context context)  
{  
    final AlarmManager m = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);  
    m.cancel(serviceShowNextSubject);  
    m.cancel(serviceDownloadSubjects); 


}
```

But the services not cancelling and keep running in background.
What can be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cancelling the alarms won't stop the services. You have to either stop them manually, or have time stop themselves after they finish their work.

Comment: How can i stop them manually when widget is removed from the screen?

Comment: What exactly do you services do? Can you make them stop themselves after finishing? This is the cleaner solution.

Comment: First service downloads some data from server every X minutes, Second service refresh the widget every X seconds with new data, They need to be stopped only if widget removed from the screen.

Comment: Not quite -- if you are using AlaramManager, your download service will be started every X minutes. So you can just stop it after it's downloading. Same with the other service -- schedule it run ever X seconds (that's excessive BTW, even for a widget), and stop it when done refreshing.

Comment: I tried to stem the from inside: stopSelf() in service itself but it keeps running.

Comment: I managed to find the solution, I need to extend from IntentService and not Service and implement all the logic in onHandleIntent.

Comment: Right. IntentService does this for you in addition to starting a worker thread to execute your code.